# connecting to phpclould using netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans-7

I am trying to connect to [phpclould](http://www.phpcloud.com/) using netbeans. 
I am following the instruction writen on [eschrade blog](http://www.eschrade.com/page/connecting-to-the-zend-developer-cloud-using-netbeans-for-php/)

On the following step, I have provided all necessary information and private key
[image]

But I am getting following error when I press the test connection button

```
Cannot connect to server XXX.my.phpcloud.com
(Cause: invalid privatekey: key.ppk)
```

I know key is correct bucause I used the same key with [winScp](http://www.phpcloud.com/help/sftp-help) and it worked perfectly fine.

Any Idea?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you got the solution already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the private key must be in OpenSSH format.  Use Puttygen to load your .ppk file and then export it as an openssh key (.priv).  Then specify the .priv file in the Netbeans dialog box.

See [this link](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic18251.html).

Comment: that is what I did. I made it work. But honestly speaking I myself don't remember now. its been couple of months now.